# How to Streamline Some Haphazard Ranking Logic PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I was given an academic assignment.  Basically, I want to take an array named 'rank' through a procedure/function/service to crank out the following outputs in the following fashion:

```
    example 1 : rank = [1,3,2,1] -> [1,4,3,2]
    example 2 : rank = [1,1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,4]
    example 3 : rank = [2,1,2,3] -> [2,1,3,4]
    example 4 : rank = [2,1,2,3] -> [2,1,3,4]
    example 5 : rank = [1,1,1,1] -> [1,2,3,4]
```

Each of the elements in the initial array represent someone getting a place (like 1st place, 2nd place, etc.) in a contest or say crossing a finish line.  Each of the elements in the output array basically represent breaking ties. So, say 4 people got first place (in example 5), the first guy/gal gets 1st, the second person gets 2nd, and so on.

Now, I've got the following semi-working code:

```
<?php

class Ranker 

{
private $rank, $result, $doWork;

public function rank() {

    /* 
    rank = [1,3,2,1] -> [1,4,3,2]
    rank = [1,1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,4]
    rank = [2,1,2,3] -> [2,1,3,4]
    rank = [2,1,2,3] -> [2,1,3,4]
    rank = [1,1,1,1] -> [1,2,3,4]
    */

    $rank = array(
        "person1" => 1,
        "person2" => 1,
        "person3" => 1,
        "person4" => 1
        );
    $result = array();

    asort($rank);

    /* Get funky */
    foreach ($rank as $place) {

        $initialplace = $place;

        if (!empty($result)) {
             {
                while(in_array($place, $result)) {
                    $place++;
                    if (!in_array($place, $result)) {
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }

            foreach (array_keys($rank, $initialplace) as $key) {

                if (!array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
                    $result[$key] = $place;
                    break;
                }

            }
        } else {
            /* array_search returns first match */
            $result[array_search($initialplace, $rank)] = $initialplace;
        }
    }

    ksort($result);

    /* Printing it out */
    foreach ($result as $finalplace) {
        echo $finalplace . ' ' . array_search($finalplace, $result) . '</br>';
    }
}
}

/* Execute class function */
$ranker = new Ranker;
$doWork = $ranker->rank();

?>
```

It's semi-working because it doesn't strictly conform to the mapping scheme listed above.  For example, it'll take [1,1,1,1] and spit out [4,3,2,1].  This may not really be an issue given that there's some flexibility in the use-case that I need it for.  But I do have two questions:

(1) How can I clean up my code and make it way better/more efficient - (I'm not a PHP guy).

(2) How can I change my code to make it conform more precisely to the initial mappings in examples 1-5 above?